# Working with multiple screens in AndroidStudio (using Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

**I'm trying to build an app in Android studio (using Kotlin),where I use 2 screens (activity's).**

To go from the MainActivity to another Activity, I use a floatingActionButton.

**How can I transfer a data from a TextView in the MainActivity to a TextView in the other Activity?**
That doesn't work and when I go back to the MainActivity all entered data is gone, without leaving the program.

Comment: to transfer data from one activity to another, you might do a lot of things, and the easier probably is to use `Intent`, but without code, there is no way to help you

Answer (score 0):

To pass data between two activities, you will need to use the Intent class via which you are starting the Activity and just before startActivity for ActivityB, you can populate it with data via the Extra objects. In your case, it will be the content of the EditText or Textview.

**ActivityA onClickListener**

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),ActivityB.class);

//Set the Data to pass
EditText txtInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtInput);
String txtData = txtInput.getText().toString();
i.putExtra("txtData", txtData);

startActivity(i);
```

Now in ActivityB, you can write code in the onCreate to get the Intent that launched it and extract out the data passed to it.

**ActivityB onCreate**

```
Intent i = getIntent();
//The second parameter below is the default string returned if the value is not there. 
String txtData = i.getExtras().getString("txtData","");
EditText txtInput2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtInput2);
txtInput2.setText(txtData);
```

And if you want to have data of ActivityB  in ActivityA you can do this vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for the support. I haven't found the solution yet. (I use Kottin by the way). Can I somehow show the code I'm using?